# Vertical scroll bar not showing in html table populated with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, scrollbar

I am having trouble with setting a vertical scrollbar in a simple HTML table. The table keeps extending with no scrollbar, needing the user to use the browser's bar to read it until the end. The table has the following HTML code:

```
<div id="table">
  <table id="mytable">
  </table>
</div>
```

and the following JavaScript functions populate the table at runtime:

```
function addTableHeader(){
  var table = document.getElementById('mytable')

  var header = table.createTHead()
  var row = header.insertRow(0)

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0)
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1)
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2)

  cell1.innerHTML = "<b>Category</b>"
  cell2.innerHTML = "<b>Rating</b>"
  cell3.innerHTML = "<b>Price</b>"
}

// dots are passed correctly, in fact the data shows up with no problems
function addTableRow(dot){
  d_row_filter = [dot.prime_genre, dot.user_rating, dot.price]
  var table = document.getElementById('mytable')

  var row = table.insertRow(-1)

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0)
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1)
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2)

  cell1.innerHTML = d_row_filter[0]
  cell2.innerHTML = d_row_filter[1]
  cell3.innerHTML = d_row_filter[2]
}
```

Here's the CSS code:

```
table {
    overflow-y: auto;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 1000px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    height: 300px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
```

Don't know if it can be useful, but I noticed that every row is contained in the thead and there is no tbody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I made this example for you, if you don't understand anything, just tell me :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <title>some title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    #table-container {
      height: 300px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      /*to prevent it from taking the whole width of the body*/
      display: inline-block;
    }

    #table-container table {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 0.7em;
    }

    #table-container table tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #d9d9d9;
    }

    .fa-star {
      color: lightgreen;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- give a good names so anyone reads your code can understand it -->
  <div id="table-container">
    <table></table>
  </div>

  <script>
    // declare it only once to use it anywhere
    let table = document.querySelector("#table-container table");

    function addTableHeader() {
      // simple and better for reading
      table.innerHTML += "<tr><th>Category</th><th>Rating</th><th>Price</th><tr>";
    }

    function addTableRow(dot) {
      /* I'm using `template strings` and it's ES6 feature, if you don't know it check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals */
      table.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${dot.prime_genre}</td><td>${dot.user_rating}</td><td>${dot.price}</td><tr>`; 
    }

    //-- Testing ----------------------------------------------------
    addTableHeader();
    for(let i = 0;i < 200;i++) {
      // I'm just simulating a filled table so you see the result of scrolling
      addTableRow({prime_genre: `a${i + 1}`, user_rating: `<i class="fa fa-star"></i>`.repeat(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1)), price: "$" + (Math.random() * 20 + 10).toFixed(2)});
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```